# Simulate a 13 inch display (Windows or Mac)

Tags: windows, laptop, display

Is there any way to simulate a 13 inch display on a Windows or Mac laptop with a larger display? Some tool that would resize all windows, the start menu, etc. to take up less space? Reason is I am thinking of buying a 13 inch laptop and want to see how it is working with a smaller screen.

Comment: Just saying 13 inches isnt enough information.  Resolution, DPI, etc will play a big factor.

Comment: You could always start up a vm with windows on it. take a tape measure to your screen and make it the same size, then get a nice black background for your host, and just work on the vm like that for a while. That should give you a pretty good idea of the kinds of issues you'll likely face.